# ¿Como pausar y reanudar un Thread en Java?

Tags: java, hilos

Hola estoy creando un programa el cual enciende la cámara de mi laptop, este programa maneja hilos en Java, estoy intentando pausar un hilo para permitir que otro hilo realice su ejecución usando un toggleButton, pero veo que los métodos de **suspend()** y **resume()** estan obsoluetos, quisiera saber como podría manejar estos hilos.

**Esta es mi clase que crea el primer hilo y me permite activar la cámara de mi laptop**

```
class VideoSepia extends Thread {

    boolean Running = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (this.Running) {
            BufferedImage src = webcam.getImage();
            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Sepia(src)));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        this.Running = false;
    }

}
```

**Esta es mi otra clase, la que permite cambiar el color a la imagen, lo que busco es poder pausar el hilo1 que ejecuta la clase Video y poner a ejecutar el hilo 2 el cual ejecuta la clase VideoGray**

```
class VideoGray extends Thread {

    boolean Running = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (this.Running) {
            BufferedImage src = webcam.getImage();
            ColorConvertOp op
                    = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
            BufferedImage dest = op.filter(src, null);

            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(dest));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        this.Running = false;
    }
}
```

**Esto es lo que tengo en mi ToggleButton, la variable vd pertence a la clase creada antes de Video y la variable vdg pertenece a la clase VideoGray creados al inicio de la clase principal, la variable vd es puesta correr al inicio de la clase principal para que cuando ejecute el programa pues se incicie, entonces cuando selecciono el boton busco pausar ese hilo vd y hacer que el hilo vdg se ejecute.**

```
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    System.out.println(jToggleButton1.isSelected());

    if (jToggleButton1.isSelected()) {
            vd.suspend();
            vdg.resume();
    } 

}
```

Comment: al final de cada vez que le doy suspend() ?

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente no hay una buena forma de hacer esto.

[Lo que propone Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) es emplear una variable controlada por el hilo principal que vaya siendo comprobada por el Thread regularmente. De forma que si la variable se establece a `true`, ejecute el método `wait()` parándose él mismo (esto sería la sustitución de `suspend()`. Para reemplazar `resume()`, el hilo principal llamaría al método `notify()` para levantar el proceso.

El ToggleButton cambiaría los procesos así:

```
// Flags de estado de los procesos, inicializados como corresponda en la logica de tu programa
private boolean vd_suspended = false;            // Flag de estado para VideoSepia
private boolean vdg_suspended = true;            // Flag de estado para VideoGray
final static Object vd_monitor = new Object();   // Monitor para VideoSepia
final static Object vdg_monitor = new Object();  // Monitor para VideoGray

private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    System.out.println(jToggleButton1.isSelected());

    if (jToggleButton1.isSelected()) {
        // Actualiza el estado de los threads como corresponda
        vd_suspended = true;     // El proceso vd deberia ejecutar wait();
        vdg_suspended = false;
        // Emplea el monitor de vdg
        synchronized(vdg_monitor) {
            vdg_monitor.notify(); // Levanta el proceso vdg
        }
    }
    // Para el caso contrario solo hay que intercambiar los valores
    else {
        vdg_suspended = true; // Detiene vdg
        vd_suspended = false; // Habilita la continuacion de vd
        // Notifica a vd con su monitor correspondiente
        synchronized(vd_monitor) {
            vd_monitor.notify(); // Levanta el proceso vd
        }
    }

}
```

Y los Threads se ejecutarían así:

**VideoSepia**

```
class VideoSepia extends Thread {

    boolean Running = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (this.Running) {
            BufferedImage src = webcam.getImage();
            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Sepia(src)));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
                // El Thread se para si su flag esta a true
                // Primera comprobacion en IF para evitar entrar en bloque synchronized
                if (vd_suspended) {
                    synchronized(vd_monitor) {
                        while (vd_suspended)
                            wait();
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        this.Running = false;
    }

}
```

**VideoGray**

```
class VideoGray extends Thread {

    boolean Running = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (this.Running) {
            BufferedImage src = webcam.getImage();
            ColorConvertOp op
                    = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
            BufferedImage dest = op.filter(src, null);

            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(dest));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
                // El Thread se para si su flag esta a true
                // Primera comprobacion en IF para evitar entrar en bloque synchronized
                if (vdg_suspended) {
                    synchronized(vdg_monitor) {
                        while (vdg_suspended)
                            wait();
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        this.Running = false;
    }
}
```

No he probado el código, por lo que puede que haya que corregir algun detalle además de ajustarlo a la lógica del programa. Pero creo que se entiende el concepto.

**Algunas cosas a tener en cuenta**

- Tanto la llamada a `notify()` como a `wait()` deben ir en bloques `synchronized()` empleando el monitor correspondiente (también se puede usar el propio thread si lo tienes en una variable en el hilo principal).
- Si no se usa `synchronized()`, se deben declarar las variables de estado como `volatile`.
- Las llamadas a `wait()` deben ir en `try{...}catch` y arrojan el mismo error que `Thread.sleep()`, por lo que recomiendan ponerlo a continuación (para que el hilo no se duerma nada más reanudarse).
- Los threads deben poder acceder a las variables de estado (declarandolas como clases internas de la clase principal, por ejemplo, o mediante otro mecanismo).

Comment: intente como me dijiste y se queda bloqueada la cámara

Comment: Es posibleque tengas que ajustar el comportamiento en función de tu programa, ya que no tengo el código completo. En cualquier caso, a veces los hilos concurrentes son confusos; puedes poner unos prints antes y despues de cada notify y wait para comprobar qué hilo se activa o se desactiva, y si están recibiendo las señales correctamente. A veces, por una u otra razón los threads pueden no recibir la señal.

Comment: De todas formas, no es una solución muy buena que digamos. Pero es lo que propone Oracle. No hay una forma adecuada de hacerlo actualmente.

Comment: la verdad estoy cerca de completar el programa pero lo unico que me cuesta es intercambiar los hilos en el momento adecuado, soy nuevo en esta pagina, no se como podria hacer para que miraras todo el codigo.

Comment: Gracias a todos, logre conseguir una solución gracias a ustedes.